# Is it possible to preserve the case of an HTTP GET request in ColdFusion MX 7?

Tags: http, coldfusion, coldfusion-7

Is it possible to preserve the case of the GET field names in ColdFusion MX 7 (the case is preserved in CF9)? I've searched tirelessly for an answer but all solutions seem to be POST specific, whereas this is a GET.

N.B. I am aware that RFC2616 states that HTTP field names are case-insensitive, but we're all aware how easy specifications can be deviated from...

**EXAMPLE:**

Given the following ColdFusion script (let's call it '**url-case-test.cfm**'):

```
<html>
    <body>
        <cfoutput>
            #structKeyList(url)#
        </cfoutput>
    </body>
</html>
```

And navigating to this script using the following parameter decorated URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/cfusion/url-case-test.cfm?name1=value1&name2=value2&name3=value3
```

I get the output:

```
NAME1,NAME2,NAME3
```

Any suggestions on how I preserve the case? Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just curious, but why would you need this? ColdFusion variables are case insensitive, so name1 and NAME1 would be treated as the same variable.

Comment: We have an existing script on a client site that is tightly coupled with the case sensitivity of the field names. If the application had been written correctly from the beginning then, yes, case sensitivity should not matter...

Comment: Is the 'script' on the client site ColdFusion? If it is, again, it _shouldn't_ matter. Curiosity is still piqued.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Another option is using getParameterMap() which returns a *case-sensitive* structure of parameters.

```
<cfset map = getPageContext().getRequest().getParameterMap()>
<cfoutput>#structKeyList(map)#</cfoutput>
```

Answer (score 5):

I think the only thing you're going to be able to do is parse the CGI.QUERY_STRING value.

```
<cfset paramList="" />
<cfloop list="#CGI.QUERY_STRING#" index="qsparam" delimiters="&">
  <cfset paramList=listAppend(paramList,listFirst(qsparam,"=")) />
</cfloop>
<cfoutput>#paramList#</cfoutput>
```

Don't store the URL parameters in a structure as keys, though, or you'll lose your case all over again.

This is obviously not ideal, as any URL values you've set via cfparam or cfset (or any other way manipulations of the URL object) will get lost.

Comment: Actually, you can set a structure key to the correct case. if you use bracket notation to set the variable in the structure, it will keep the same case. If you do <cfset session["UserName"] = "batman" /> then dump the session, you will see 'UserName' instead of 'USERNAME'

Comment: @Scott: In CF7? I thought that was a relatively recent development.

Comment: I was not sure. I checked and CF7 does not have that feature.

Comment: Al, I am not sure when that feature was added but I know its been around for quite sometime. @Leigh - CF7 does not store the structure key in specific case when using structName["keyName"] = "foo"? I would have bet its been there for longer than CF7

Comment: @Scott - No, you are right after all. I was thinking of something different. Under CF7 `structName["keyName"]` does return `keyName`. I was thinking of how getParameterMap() preserves two keys that differ only in case `"keyName"` and `"keYNAMe"`. Whereas a CF structure will still collapse them into a single key `"keyName"`. But I think that would apply in any version.

Answer (score 3):

Which version of CF are you using? In ACF9 and Railo 3.3 case is definitely preserved.

I've a bit changed your sample URL for testing purposes:

```
?nAmE1=ValuE1&name2=value2&name3=value3
```

Code:

```
<cfdump var="#url#" />

<cfloop collection="#url#" item="key">
    <cfoutput>#key#<br/></cfoutput>
</cfloop>

<cfoutput>#structKeyList(url)#</cfoutput>
```

ACF9:

[image]

Railo:

[image]

Comment: Very relevant question actually, it's both version 7 and 9 of ColdFusion we're supporting. Like you've just highlighted, case is preserved in CF9 but not in CFMX7. I'll update my original question to be more specific about the version.

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge it is not possible. Coldfusion always Capitalize structure key name. If have limited list of URL keys then just create comma separated new key list and pass as separate URL key. This is what I had use before.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to maintain case you would just use array notation to build the struct within your loop.

```
<cfset paramStruct = StructNew()>
<cfloop list = "#CGI.QUERY_STRING#" index="i" delimiters="&">
  <cfset paramStruct[ listFirst(i,"=") ] = listLast(i,"=")>
</cfloop>

<cfdump var="#paramStruct#">
```

I have not tested this but I assume it will work.

Comment: *I have not tested this* Always test before posting and check older answers/comments. As [mentioned in the comments here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6817182/104223) a structure will not work.

Comment: You cay use this java library as well, I have tested this!

<cfset HtmlToolsObj = CreateObject('java', 'coldfusion.util.HTMLTools') />
<cfdump var="#HtmlToolsObj.parseQueryString(cgi.query_string)#" />